# Is there a way to download a USDZ and place it in the reality kit scene?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

I want to create an app that uses reality kit rcproject to augment content in AR. I know how to create an entity in Reality Composer but the problem is that I have multiple models. I can't place them as objects in Reality Composer and ship it into the app. Like I do for an ARKit app, I want to download models from the site and then place them in the AR Experience made with Reality Kit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the model and then try this out:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "path/to/MyEntity.usdz")
let entity = try? Entity.load(contentsOf: url)
```

for more details: [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/stored_entities/loading_entities_from_a_file)

Comment: Will check this out. Sounds like a solution to me. Thanks.

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also you can import the model in RealityComposer.

[image]